# Trying to count the number of each character in the string C program

Tags: c

I'm trying to count the number of each character in the string with using a searching function and adding every time it appears.

Here's my program so far

```
            #include<stdio.h>


            int countCharactersCaseSensitive(char *inStr, char);

            int main()
            {
                char ascii[52];
                int capital = 65;
                int i;
                for (i = 0; i <26; i++)
                {
                    ascii[i] = capital;
                    capital++;
                }
                int lower = 97;
                for (i=26; i< 52; i++)
                {
                    ascii[i] = lower;
                    lower++;
                }


                char *str = "Programming Assignment";
                int count[52];
                for (i=0;i<52;i++)
                {
                    char check = ascii[i];
                    count[i] = countCharactersCaseSensitive(str,check);

                }

                    for(i=0;i<52;i++)
                {
                    printf("%c%10d\n",ascii[i],count[i]);
                }

            }


            int countCharactersCaseSensitive(char *inStr, char check)
            {
                int i;
                int count = 0;
                int length = strlen(inStr);
                for (i=0;i<length;i++)
                {
                    if(check == *inStr)
                    {
                        inStr++;
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                return count;
            }
```

But it only checks for P, how do i fix this to check the other characters in the string?

Comment: I don't think that's why his program doesn't work.

Comment: it was just a stylistic suggestion, the real problem wasn't going to go unanswered for very long :)

Comment: Currently you have a very wasteful `O(N*52)` algorithm.  You can do this in `O(N)` time if you index your count array using a value derived from the actual letter.  That way you only examine each character in the string once.

Comment: @user2976944 It was a wrong stylistic suggestion. Why would you cast an `int` to an `int`? (Even if you erroneously think that `'A'` is a `char`, which it isn't because this is tagged C and not C++, the cast would be unnecessary, superfluous and consequently **wrong,** because implicit conversion happens between integral types. All the cast does is it decreases readability, which is the **very last thing** you want to do with your code.)

Comment: OK you are right. But we wouldn't want to imply that int capital = 65; is somehow better because I made an error.

Comment: @user2976944 Surely it is better than assuming `capital = 65`! I don't mean to deny that by any means. If I could only choose between `capital = 65` and `capital = (int)'A'`, I'd definitely go with the latter. If *I* were to write this code, I'd write this as `char capital = 'A'`, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (i=0;i<length;i++)
{
    if(check == *inStr)
    {
        inStr++;
        count++;
    }
}
```

You only advance inStr when you found the check character. You need to advance it every iteration.

```
for (i = 0; i < length; i++, inStr++)
{
    if (check == *inStr)
    {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

because of this

```
if(check == *inStr) 
{
    inStr++;
    count++;
}
```

You increment the pointer only if it matches, and since the first char is a `P` and that one occurs only one time, you get only 1 for `P`

You need to increment outside of the if statement.

either do

```
if(check == *inStr) 
{
    count++;
}
inStr++;
```

or

```
if(check == inStr[i]) 
{
    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually advancing through the string you're trying to search.
I'd recommend either of these two changes:

```
int length = strlen(inStr);
for (i=0;i<length;i++)
{
     if(check == inStr[i])
     {
         count++;
     }
}
```

or

```
char * strPtr;

for (strPtr = inStr; *strPtr; strPtr++)
{
     if(check == *strPtr)
     {
         count++;
     }
}
```